# pythonic way to scrape google search box results using beautiful soup

Tags: python, pandas, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a CSV with the following columns, celebrity name, url, raw_html.

The raw_html is the html associated to a google search when you search `celebrity_name` + `age`
e.g. The raw html associated to the following search,

'https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=DHMDX4XDLIqstQb1grfAAQ&q=' + 'Jennifer' + '+' + 'Lopez' + '+' + 'age'

resulting in this google page:
https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=DHMDX4XDLIqstQb1grfAAQ&q=Jennifer+Lopez+age

I want to store the age associated to all of the celebrities in my CSV. The problem I'm encountering is when a celebrity does not have a google answer box associated to it.

I get the error :
`list index out of range`

When in fact I want to store that year as a `NaN` value

My code :

```
age = {}
for iid, html in celeb_df[['celeb_id', 'raw_html']].values:
    if html.find_all('div', {'class' : ['HwtpBd gsrt PZPZlf']}) != None:
        for year in html.find_all('div', {'class' : ["Z0LcW XcVN5d", "Z0LcW XcVN5d AZCkJd"]})[0]: 
            print(iid, year)
            age[iid] = year
```

What I want is a dictionary where the key is the celebrity id and the value is the age associated to that celebrity. If the celebrity does not have a google search box answer associated to it then I want to store the value as a 'NaN'

What's the best way to proceed with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
age = {}
for iid, html in celeb_df[['institution_id', 'raw_html']].values:
    if html.find_all('div', {'class' : ['Z0LcW XcVN5d AZCkJd']}):
        for year in html.find_all('div', {'class' : ["Z0LcW XcVN5d AZCkJd"]})[0]: 
            print(iid, year)
            age[iid] = year
    else:
        print(iid, 'NaN')
        age[iid] = 'NaN'
```

Answer (score 2):

To get return an age value as `NaN`, you can surround it with `try/except` block, like so:

```py
try:
  age = soup.find('div', class_='class_name').text
except:
  age = None
```

Code and example in [online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Google-Scrape-Answer-Box-Age-and-write-to-csv):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, lxml, csv

headers = {
    'User-agent':
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

# celebrity list
celeb_list = ['Jennifer Lopez', 'Chuck Norris', 'Jason Statham', 'Jackie Chan']

with open('awesome_file.csv', mode='w') as csv_file:
  # defining column names
  fieldnames = ['Celebrity name', 'Age']
  # defining .csv writer
  # https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter
  writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
  # writing (creating) columns
  writer.writeheader()

  # collecting scraped data
  celeb_data = []
  
  # iterating over celebrity names list()
  for celeb in celeb_list:
    html = requests.get(f'https://www.google.com/search?q={celeb} age', headers=headers).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

    name = celeb
    try:
      age = soup.select_one('.XcVN5d').text
    except:
      age - None
    # because we have a csv.DictWriter() we converting to the required format
    # dict() keys should be exactly the same as fieldnames, otherwise it will throw an error
    celeb_data.append({
      'Celebrity name': name,
      'Age': age
    })
  # iterating over celebrity data list() that became dict() and writing it to the .csv
  for data in celeb_data:
    writer.writerow(data)

# CSV output from created file:
'''
Celebrity name,Age
Jennifer Lopez,51 years
Chuck Norris,81 years
Jason Statham,53 years
Jackie Chan,67 years
'''
```

---

Alternatively, you can do the same thing using [Google Direct Answer Box API](https://serpapi.com/direct-answer-box-api) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free trial of 5,000 searches.

Essentially, the main differences in this particular case are:

- you don't have to figure out how to grab certain elements from the page, it's already done for the end-user.
- you get faster responses (check out in the online IDE to test) with a `JSON` output.
- you don't have to maintain the parser if something is changed in the HTML page (*CSS selector, element, or something else*).

Code to integrate:

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch
import os, csv

celeb_list = ['Jennifer Lopez', 'Chuck Norris', 'Jason Statham', 'Jackie Chan']

with open('serpapi_solution.csv', mode='w') as csv_file:
  fieldnames = ['Celebrity name', 'Age']
  writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
  writer.writeheader()

  celeb_data = []

  for celeb in celeb_list:
    params = {
      "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
      "engine": "google",
      "q": f"{celeb} age",
      "google_domain": "google.com",
    }

    search = GoogleSearch(params)
    results = search.get_dict()

    name = celeb
    try:
      age = results['answer_box']['answer']
    except:
      age = None
    print(age)

    celeb_data.append({
      'Celebrity name': name,
      'Age': age
    })

  for data in celeb_data:
    writer.writerow(data)

# CSV output from created file:
'''
Celebrity name,Age
Jennifer Lopez,51 years
Chuck Norris,81 years
Jason Statham,53 years
Jackie Chan,67 years
'''
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.

Answer (score 1):

subsequently, you can also use something like the following :

```
import bs4
import requests

result = bs4.BeautifulSoup(requests.get('https://www.nhc.noaa.gov/gis/').content, features='html.parser')
for link in result.find('table').find_all('a'):
    print(link.attrs['href'])
```